# Slow read performance on Mongo under Centos 6

Tags: mongodb, networking

I successfully basic configure my replica set, but i noticed slow read performance. I have 2 mongo servers and 1 arbiter in my replica set. All are running on Centos 6.3 minimal setup (just database).

I also have single mongo instance on another  Windows server 2012.

Before i build my replica set, my web server was on same OS as Mongo (that windows instance). Performance was fine, results was like

C# .NET 4.5 (IIS and Mongo on same VM) Read 2000 rows : ~250ms at AvgObj 2600 bytes

Now with my replica set i have very slow read performance. When my web server access replica set, i`m getting result like

C# .NET 4.5 (separated, IIS and Mongo on Centos Replica) Read 2000 rows : ~2500ms at AvgObj 2600 bytes

I tried to read from my single Mongo instant from remote IIS and result is like

C# .NET 4.5 (separated, IIS and Single Mongo on Windows) Read 2000 rows : ~600ms at AvgObj 2600 bytes

All servers are running in single physical machine with Hyper-V core server.

Im using latest C# MongoDB Driver 1.7 version. From what i tested in command shell, on all mongo servers my query is executed in 10ms.

Can anyone give me suggestions why my replica set on separated Centos servers have slow read performance? is it network, drivers or what else?

My C# config is

```
            var server1 = new MongoServerAddress("1.0.0.1"); //primary
            var server2 = new MongoServerAddress("1.0.0.2"); /secundary
            var servers = new List<MongoServerAddress> {server1, server2};

            var safe = new MongoClientSettings
                {

                    Servers = servers,
                    ReplicaSetName = "rs0",
                    ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.ReplicaSet,
                    WriteConcern = new WriteConcern
                        {
                            Journal = false,
                            W = 1
                        },
                    ReadPreference = new ReadPreference
                        {
                            ReadPreferenceMode = ReadPreferenceMode.PrimaryPreferred
                        }
                };
```

Comment: Are you connecting to the mongos process or to the primary directly?  What is your collection structure, indexes? And what is your query?  Please update the question with these information, so that someone might be able to help you!

Comment: As u see, i have ReadPreferenceMode.PrimaryPreferred. Average size on document is 2600 bytes. I have index, and directly in mongo shell that query is executed in 10ms. Getting results back in c# taks 2.5 sec, dno why

Comment: You have to update the collection as well as the query in the question (that you are using), so check on the possible reasons.

Comment: I assume you are using the regular Network Adaptors (non-legacy) in your VMs? Also, did you install Integration Services on your Linux VMs http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34603

Comment: chue x, ill check and test your answer next days.

Comment: @NovkovskiStevoBato - I added my comment above as an answer, in case it does solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For best performance on Hyper V, make sure you are using the regular Network Adaptors (non-legacy), and that you install Integration Services inside of the guest operating system.

For CentOS 6.x, you can install the Integration Services from here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34603

If you find that your VM was using a legacy network adapter, note that when you add a new adapter you'll have to reconfigure the networking inside of the guest (CentOS) operating system.

Comment: i already installed Integration Services, tomorrow ill change their network adapters to regular and ill post my result here :)

Comment: that was the problem! Thanks!

Comment: @chue x the link is broken. please add a new link

Comment: @sureshpareek - I do not have time to test, but here are a couple of versions: [Integration Services 4.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51612&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True) and [Integration Services 4.2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55106&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True&fa43d42b-25b5-4a42-fe9b-1634f450f5ee=True).  What's the difference?  It appears that 4.1 is for legacy guest OS and 4.2 is for the latest guest OS - again I do not have time to test, so READ the docs!

Answer (score 1):

In the Mongo shell you are typically getting back the first 10 records - in .NET you are getting back the first 101 records or 1 MB (whichever comes first).  If you are opening a cursor and then timing the iterations, you will find that this can be extremely slow compared to the 10 record retrieval from the shell.

Try running a JS loop to retrieve all records in the shell and see how long that takes.  Note you should run both the shell and the C# connection through your mongos connection if you have one up and running.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to measure how long findOne() takes rather than iterating over a cursor?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a conclusive answer, but what I'd do at this point is just debug the mongo connection without the c# application in between: Querying using the mongo shell and connecting to the remote server (both centos and windows, both configured as replicas with the same data).
If there is a significant difference here, then I'd look at the VM/OS configuration (network adapters, network configuration, etc).

If there is no difference, I'd play around with the mongo configuration (read preference, slaves, etc) to find out what exactly is hampering the performance.